# Common practice with validating emails?

Tags: regex, email, email-validation

I read an article the other day that briefly touched base on some common validation flaws in most modern websites, and I decided to do some research on it.

Turns out, MOST websites, and email providers (hotmail, yahoo) are being TOO STRICT with their validation.

-

**In section 2.3.10 of RFC 2821**

> Consequently, and due to a long history of problems when intermediate hosts have attempted to optimize transport by modifying them, the local-part MUST be interpreted and assigned semantics only by the host specified in the domain part of the address.

**In section 3.4.1 of RFC 2822** It goes into more detail as to what the user-interpreted string should be!

> An addr-spec is a specific Internet identifier that contains a locally interpreted string followed by the at-sign character ("@", ASCII value 64) followed by an Internet domain.  The locally interpreted string is either a **quoted-string** or a **dot-atom**.

**In section 3.2.4 of RFC 2822** And finnally, tells us that a dot-atom may include any of the following characters

> $ & * - = ^ ` | ~ # % ' + / ? _ { }

**In RFC 3696** It goes further to display a list of valid emails.

- "Abc\@def"@example.com
- "Fred Bloggs"@example.com
- "Joe\Blow"@example.com
- "Abc@def"@example.com
- customer/department=shipping@example.com
- $A12345@example.com
- !def!xyz%abc@example.com
- _somename@example.com

Now, *My question* to all you guys out there, how strict should I validate emails. According to the RCF? or according to the crowd. And what are the majority of people out there validating too?

Comment: Are you validating email content or the email address or other fields (to, from, subject)?

Comment: @DOK: Im talking about websites using regex patterns or other methods to see if a email is valid or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use a regex to validate emails. regular-expressions.info has a [good page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html), including a regex that is supposed to conform to RFC 2822.

Another question is which ISP allows email addresses like: !def!xyz%abc@example.com, customer/department=shipping@example.com, "Fred Bloggs"@example.com ? I suspect very few, if any. I think you don't have to worry about these odd cases as they are very rarely used (to the best of my knowledge - I have never seen any addresses of these forms in use).